# Contact form 7 not working with wordpress pop up plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

I have added a pop up plugin in my WordPress website called https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-popup/ it's showing perfectly on the specific page I have selected.In the pop up there are three fields "Name,Email and Phone number"

when I submitted then I don't receive any email in my inbox.where is the problem.I have used contact form 7 and created the contact form specially for the pop up and paste the contact form Shortcode in the pop up field.

How I will be able to receive email form the pop up?

Please help me.

Best Regards,

Wasim Rana.

Comment: did you set up correctly ? or did you put your email in contact form 7?

Comment: Yes, I have set up there my own email Id but I don't receive any mail.where is the problem actually?

Comment: That plugin has a bunch of bad ratings, why don't you try with fancybox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another Solution :

*Assuming that you will not use https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-popup/

1) Download & install http://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-fancybox/

2) Shortcode from Contact Form 7 for example :

```
 [contact-form-7 id="01" title="Contact form 1"]
```

3) Paste on your page :

```
<a href="#contact_form_pop" class="fancybox">Contact Us</a>
<div style="display:none" class="fancybox-hidden">
<div id="contact_form_pop">
         [contact-form-7 id="01" title="Contact form 1"]</div>
</div>
```